# Can someone explain why print("red" == "blue" or 3 >= 3) returns True

Tags: python, logical-operators

I cant figure this out in my head.

```
>>>print("red" == "blue")
False

>>>print("red" == 3 >= 3)
False
```

so why is the following True?

```
>>> print("red" == "blue" or 3 >= 3)
True
```

someone put my brain out of its misery

Comment: When you use the Boolean `or`, only one of the conditions has to be true for it to return true. `3>=3` is true, so the whole expression is true. Check out [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) for a (lot) more.

Comment: It looks like a dupe when you compare the first snippet to the second. They don't quite match in the same way that the dupe catches people out.

Comment: Never mind, I read through the accepted answer, and if you look hard enough you can see the explanation of logial `or`.

Comment: `print("red" == 3 >= 3)` but that's not any part of your full expression. It's `"red" == "blue" or 3 >= 3` which is evaluated as `("red" == "blue") or (3 >= 3)` which is then `False or True`.

Comment: `"red" == 3 >= 3` is equivalent to `"red" == 3 and 3 >= 3`, which is why you get `False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the Boolean Operator **or**, only one of the conditions declared has to be true in order for it to return true. **3>=3 is true**, so the whole expression **is true**.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("red" == "blue" or 3 >= 3)
```

Analysis:

```
"red" == "blue" #--> False

3 >= 3 #-->True
```

Given that there is an OR operator:

```
"red" == "blue" or 3 >= 3 #--> False OR True --> True
```

Comment: Does Python let you use those quotes? Mine (3.7.7 on Win10) complains saying there's an "invalid character in identifier"

Comment: @PranavHosangadi no, it doesn't. The reason there are "smart quotes" there is probably because the author is using IE or Edge.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you used `or`.

In that specific case, `3 >= 3` returns True, and since it's needs only one True parameter, it returns True, ignoring the other condition.

Answer (score 0):

`print("red" == "blue")` #False for obvious reasons as string red is not equal to string blue.

`print("red" == 3 >= 3)` this is false as red is not equal to 3

`print("red" == "blue" or 3 >= 3)` this is true because 3 == 3